# sp_addlinkedsrvlogin doesn't work but sp_addlinkedserver does?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can add a link server with EXEC sp_addlinkedserver, (With no credentials) successfully, however, I need to provide a username and password to a server if the Windows Authentication doesn't work.

So I have tried using

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin       @rmtsrvname='ServerName',
                                 @useself=N'False',
                                 @locallogin=NULL,
                                 @rmtuser='sa',
                                 @rmtpassword='Password'
```

Which this error appears

> Msg 15015, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, Line 49
>   The server 'ServerName' does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show
>   available servers
>   .

I dont understand as looking online, I have understood the two prodcecures to be the same, but sp_addlinkedsrvlogin takes a username and password and then creates the link server. I guess I have this wrong? So if I have, is there a SQL Server Procedure that will do what I want?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have understood the two prodcecures to be the same

Incorrect. [`sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx) is documented as:

> Creates or updates a mapping between a login on the local instance of SQL Server and a security account on a remote server.

Nowhere is said that it creates a linked server. In fact the very first argument is properly documented as:

> `@rmtsrvname` Is the name of a linked server that the login mapping applies to

You first create the linked server via `sp_addlinkedserver`, you then add the linked server login via `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear up! however, that is the problem, I need to add creditials to sp_addlinkedserver procedure, is this possible?

Comment: Refer to the product documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: Actually, I think its nothing to do with the link servers, its to do with logging on to the server to run the Stored Procedures. Thanks though, I would of kept looking at this! will mark!